# Z-index для попапа в API3.0 Яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, какие нужно задать условия, чтобы popup отображался поверх стандартных маркеров на карте?

Comment: А пример кода есть? Добавьте его к вопросу. Может вы z-index слою меток нереальный задаёте?

Comment: @YaCor' если это попап из документации, то он привязан к маркеру и находится с ним в одном контейнере на карте. Не знаю, как это фиксится средствами API, но CSS-хак выглядел бы так: `.ymaps3x0--marker:has(.popup[style="display:flex"]) { z-index: 1 !important }`